# Eclipse 4 RCP HandlerProcessingAddon start up order

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4

I have a pure e4 application with a lot of plugins.

Some of these plugins are contributing Handlers using the application model. I've noticed that with the addition of the handlers, the startup order has changed and now all of the plugins get loaded before the splashscreen progress bar has even appeared. Once it does appear it completes very quickly.

I call PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench() in my activator and within there E4Application.createE4Workbench() is called. This goes through the addons referenced in the Applicaion.e4xmi and one of them is the HandlerProcessingAddon which loops through and activates all of the handlers in the application model. Because of my dependencies between my plugins this ends up loading all of my plugins.

Once this has finished the progress bar is initialised.

This is obviously not desirable because the progress bar should be progressing as the plugins are loaded.

Here is the code I am talking about within Workbench.java

```
E4Workbench e4Workbench = e4app.createE4Workbench(getApplicationContext(), display);

            MApplication appModel = e4Workbench.getApplication();
            IEclipseContext context = e4Workbench.getContext();

            WorkbenchMigrationProcessor migrationProcessor = null;
            try {
                migrationProcessor = ContextInjectionFactory.make(WorkbenchMigrationProcessor.class, context);
            } catch (InjectionException e1) {
                WorkbenchPlugin.log(e1);
            }

            if (migrationProcessor != null && isFirstE4WorkbenchRun(appModel)
                    && migrationProcessor.isLegacyWorkbenchDetected()) {
                try {
                    WorkbenchPlugin
                            .log(StatusUtil.newStatus(IStatus.INFO, "Workbench migration started", null)); //$NON-NLS-1$
                    migrationProcessor.migrate();
                } catch (Exception e2) {
                    WorkbenchPlugin.log("Workbench migration failed", e2); //$NON-NLS-1$
                    migrationProcessor.restoreDefaultModel();
                }
            }

            // create the workbench instance
            Workbench workbench = new Workbench(display, advisor, e4Workbench
                    .getApplication(), e4Workbench.getContext());

            // prime the splash nice and early
            if (createSplash)
                workbench.createSplashWrapper();

            AbstractSplashHandler handler = getSplash();

            boolean showProgress = PrefUtil.getAPIPreferenceStore().getBoolean(
                            IWorkbenchPreferenceConstants.SHOW_PROGRESS_ON_STARTUP);

            IProgressMonitor progressMonitor = null;
            SynchronousBundleListener bundleListener = null;
            if (handler != null && showProgress) {
                progressMonitor = handler.getBundleProgressMonitor();
                if (progressMonitor != null) {
```

Is there anything I can do about this? Or do I need to place my handlers is different plugins to ensure instantiating them doesn't end up loading all of the bundles?

Comment: Note a 'pure' e4 RCP doesn't use `PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench` - this is part of 3.x compatibility mode as is `Workbench`.

Comment: So does the call to PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench  need to be replaced with anything?

Comment: A pure e4 RCP uses the existing org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application as the application id. It only uses plugins in the org.eclipse.e4.rcp feature which means that the org.eclipse.ui.xxx plugins can't be used. Any splash screen has to be set up in the LifeCycle class.